# How can I plot a line for one country throughout time via ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image]

My code is

```
ggplot(classen, aes(Year, SupDem))+
  geom_line(stat = 'summary', fun = mean, aes(color = 'mean'), linetype = 1) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c('orange')) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 5)
```

My df is:

| Country Name | Year | SupDem |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Turkiye | 1990 | 5 |
| Turkiye | 1991 | 45 |
| Turkiye | 1993 | 50 |
| US | 1990 | 80 |
| US | 1991 | 85 |
| US | 1993 | 84 |

I need to choose the country's name and then want to plot it, but I am not sure if I can choose the country within the ggplot() function.

I would like to plot Turkey and Sweden as well. But when I plot Turkey, for example, using the code below Turkey appears very different:

```
ggplot(classen, aes(x=Year, y=mean(SupDem), colour= "Turkey")) + 
  geom_line(size=0.6) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("orange")) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 9)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the `color` should be `Country Name` rather than `class`, and `y` should be `SupDem`

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(Year, SupDem, colour = `Country Name`)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Or, if you want more modern styling, something like:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(Year, SupDem, colour = `Country Name`)) +
  geom_line(size = 1) +
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c('orange', 'deepskyblue4')) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16)
```

[image]

---

**EDIT**

To add the mean value to the plot, we can do:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(Year, SupDem)) +
  geom_line(aes(colour = `Country Name`), size = 1) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = `Country Name`), size = 3) +
  geom_line(stat = 'summary', fun = mean, aes(color = 'mean'), linetype = 2) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c('gray', 'orange', 'deepskyblue4')) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

**Data taken from question in reproducible format**

```r
df <- structure(list(`Country Name` = c("Turkiye", "Turkiye", "Turkiye", 
 "US", "US", "US"), Year = c(1990L, 1991L, 1993L, 1990L, 1991L, 
1993L), SupDem = c(5L, 45L, 50L, 80L, 85L, 84L)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: Also, I would like to know how to take the average of countries when we plot them

Comment: The graph has been so different from what I had before in Python. I do not know where I made a mistake.

Comment: Can you include a picture in your question to illustrate what you are looking for?

Comment: I tried to explain it better, and I edited I hope it helps. Many thanks Allan.

Comment: @user19562955 you can't just write color = "Turkey". This will plot all the countries in the same line. You need to put the name of the column that contains the country names (in your sample data this column was called `Country Name` but it might be called something else in your real data?) `If you only want Turkey and Sweden, you need to filter your data to only include those two countries before passing it to ggplot.

Comment: In the real dataset it is called Country. But the problem each year for each country there should be one value. However, it seems there are many values for each year. How can it happen and why?

Comment: But at the same time, I want to get the average support for democracy (taking the average of all countries across time.).